# Angular 4 Module Not Found

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Angular 4 says module is missing. But the problem is that module is not the part of application. I have not imported that module anywhere. It asks for a module that was not the part of application ever

My Solution:
For the first time app does not run it says module missing, but when i open and save my app.module.ts it works fine. But this is a temporary solution. I don't know why each time i have to save my app.module.ts

It Might be a cache issue of code editor or something else but i'm not sure
I have attached the screenshots
Please Help

App.module.ts
[image: app.module.ts]

Error:
[image: error message]

Comment: Are you sure you're not importing dashboard.module.ts anywhere?

Comment: yes i was 100% sure, i solved problem by deleting Visual studio cache and everthing worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Is appRouter your routing module? Check if you have added it as a route there.